# How to query multiple databases from different SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

We have approx. 8 odd SQL Servers used for different purposes like inserting data in 1 server, update in another etc. (or connecting to only that database based on user’s region).

The problem is sometimes query for data needs to be done from multiple SQL Server databases. So say, I have an `Id` property, and based on the `Id` data needs to be retrieved from multiple of these 8 servers (if there is an Id match, so basically querying all database).

So basically the server which the user is logged into, will use “Linked Server” functionality and connect to other SQL Servers (with the server which the user is currently on acts as the source SQL Server), and using “UNION” functionality to club all data.

As a lot of transactions is taking place each day, this approach is not feasible, performance wise.

So any recommendations on a better approach to achieve the same above functionality. I read a concept called “**Server Groups**” but not sure of it.

The application is made in .Net Web Forms using Jquery/Ajax/HTML/API and ADO.NET.

Comment: More research into "data needs to be retrieved from multiple of these 8 servers" has to be done.  When the need is there, then do it.  Or replicate critical data around multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .net application which is outside these 8 servers can't you establish individual connections and pass the ID from .net app to these servers ?

As far as I know "Server Group" is a concept in SSMS which helps you to group the servers and can run common scripts at same time.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. We are passing ID from .net app to these servers, but the linked server methodology is used when we are creating custom reports. So for custom reports we need to fetch data from multiple sql server, and create reports.

Comment: Try Open Source Pentaho Business Analytics, same can be linked at BI tool level.. so you dont have to worry about linking them at SQL Level  https://www.capterra.com/p/78014/Pentaho-Business-Analytics/